Java Path.getName() truncating encoded percent sign
.Net dev here, somewhat new to java. I have the following snippet of code. I'm trying to get the last segment of the the encoded url, but as you can see it's cutting off the trailing "%25" and making that just "%". That causes the URlDecoder.Decode to fail because the string is no longer properly encoded.
Ideally I'd like to use Path.getName() because from what I gather that won't include query params. Also I'd really like to avoid 3rd party libraries if possible (this seems like a pretty basic task). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, is there a way to get Path.getName() to not cut off the encoded "%25" at the end?
    var playerSrcPath = URI.create("https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/guests/Please+Submit+to+Any%25").getPath();
    var path = Paths.get(playerSrcPath);
    var lastSegment = path.getName(path.getNameCount() - 1).toString();         
    System.out.println(lastSegment); 

    // this errors, lastSegment got cut off, no longer properly encoded.
    var playerAbbr = URLDecoder.decode(lastSegment, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);        
    System.out.println(playerAbbr); 


You should be encoding finally, not decoding

is getName()really cutting off the %25?  I got path = \api\v1\guests\Please+Submit+to+Any% and lastSegment = Please+Submit+to+Any% -- ( %25 is converted to % by URI.create() and the % is there even after getName() )

maybe new URL(...) instead of URI.create(...) for playerAbbr = "Please Submit to Any%"

@user85421, yea thats the problem then, the URI.create is decoding the %25. Then decode errors because the last segment is no longer properly encoded. I can't re-encode the last segment, because then it will double encode it, as the url is already encoded when I get it from the API call.

In utf-8 %25 is a percent sign, I think that's your issue. If you need the "25" the url would have to be like this
...Please+Submit+to+Any%2525

If you're using the % sign as sort of separator, you can then remove it in the resulting string with playerAbbr.replace("%", "")
Let me know if that helps :)

Hi there, I'm not tyrin to get the 25 at the end. The url is already encoded, so the encoded last segment is "Please+Submit+to+Any%25". Decoding that should get you "Please Submit to Any%". The problem is URI.create() is removing the encoded "%25", and replacing with just "%".

The problem is the + sign would not be decoded as a space, in that case  you should try with Please%20Submit%20to%20Any%2525

Yea I can't control the formatting of the url because it's coming from an external API. The url is definitely already UTF-8 encoded. If I do URIEncoder.encode("Please Submit to Any%", StandardCharsets.UTF_8), I get "Please+Submit+to+Any%25". So the problem is Path.getPath() is decoding in some way, but doesn't appear to be full UTF-8 decode. So I think I'm going to use Path.getRawPath() and then URIDecoder.decode using UTF-8, that should do the trick. Weird that Path.getPath() isn't doing the same decoding as URIDecoder.decode(item, "UTF-8").

yeah you're right, getRawPath will do the trick! Apparently getPath() decodes the response, that's why you get % instead of %25, and when you decode again it throws exception because it was already decoded

Yea but what’s weird is getPath() should also decode “+” to “ “, but it doesn’t, so it’s not doing a full UTF8 decode. But yea using getRawPath and then decoding that works.
